# Download section no longer available for shared EE account on magento.com

Tags: magento-enterprise, patches

Trying to download SUPEE-8788, we recognized that we don't have access to the EE download section anymore. The only thing we can see after switching to the shared account is the corresponding EE license info. Our client, owner of the license, told us they didn't change anything, and we had download access before.

Has anything changed on Magento's side regarding this?

Comment: Any update on this Pong? I am also in same situation.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Didn't bother contacting support, instead asked our client to get us the patch. Still interested in a solution, though …

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't belong on Magento SE but with Magento support directly.

Comment: With this reasoning, every EE question is off-topic.

Comment: @7ochem `Magento SE is for users of and developers working with the Magento e-Commerce platform.` It’s not developers only. Besides, knowing how to get access to security patches actually might be considered useful even for developers. The question also doesn’t match any of the questions-better-not-asked-criteria, so there’s no indication of being off-topic. As stated, any EE question can be sent to Magento’s support - whoever contacted them knows they don’t tell you anything useful, though -, so do you mind elaborating why this one is off-topic?

Comment: To me this is off topic because no one of the community can solve the problem, it's a bug in their system, only Magento Inc. can fix it. If you have questions about the EE/Commerce Magento webshop system or the use of the Magento portal, then of course the community can help out.

Comment: @7ochem You might have misinterpreted the nature of this site then. It’s Q&A, not T&S, it’s about finding answers, not solutions. It’s about expanding knowledge. You assume it’s a bug: how do you know? There might be a workaround, a functionality hidden to the eye of the unconscious, and if it turns out to be intended behavior instead, that would also be helpful to know. Let’s assume it really is a bug with no workaround and this site is about solutions: there’s a good chance there might even be some Magento Inc. employees amongst us.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask Magento Support. There was a recent web site upgrade (month or two back), there are some more changes coming in future (streamlining download area), but nothing I know of right now. I would ask Support to investigate.

Comment: Thought I did :)

Comment: Any update on this guys? I am also in same situation.